# Regex to insert space C#

Tags: c#, regex

I have some string. I need a regex that will replace each occurrence of symbol that is not `space + '<'` with the same symbol + `space + '<'`.

In other words if there is `'<'` without `' '` before it it must add the space.

I've tried something like :

```
string pattern = "[^ ]<";
string replacement = "$0" + "<";
string result = Regex.Replace(html, pattern, replacement);
```

Obviously not working as I want.

Comment: Related : [RegEx match open tags except XHTML self-contained tags](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags?rq=1)

Comment: What is the expected result in your snippet?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
   string pattern = "([^ ])<";
   string replacement = "$1" + " <";
```

You can try something like this.